# Does $\operatorname{rank}(T) = \dim(W)$ imply linear transformation is onto.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

If you have a linear transformation going from $V,W$, where $V,W$ are finite-dimensional vector spaces. Does the $\dim(\operatorname{range}(T))$ being equal to the dimension of the target space imply that the linear transformation is onto. If it does do you mind explaining why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

rank $T$ is the dimension of the range of $T$. So the range of $T$ is a subspace of $W$ that has the same dimension as $W$, hence the image is $W$, or in other words, $T$ is onto.

This argument relies on the fact that a subspace $U$ of $W$ that has the same dimension as $W$ is $W$ (call this dimension $n$). We can prove this easily.

Take a basis for $U$, it has $n$ elements, since the basis is a linearly independent subset of $W$ it can be extended to a basis of $W$, of course all the basis for $W$ have $n$ elements, so the extension consists on adding nothing, therefore the basis for $U$ is a basis for $W$ and hence $U=W$ as desired.